# Apollo codegen generate files indentation

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

When generating files with `apollo codegen:generate` files are generated with two spaces.

I couldn't find any place where I could define this configuration, e.g. **4 spaces/1 tab**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the [Apollo codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output) documentation, it does not seem to accept any param for lint configurations.

But, you could do it yourself after generating the code.

Let's assume you have a script in your `package.json` to run `apollo codegen:generate` called `generate:types` then you can just run you `tslint.json` configurations against the generated files, something like:

```
 "scripts": {
    "generate:types": "apollo codegen:generate ....",
    "generate:types:lint": "tslint --fix -c tslint.json {path-to-your-generated-files}",
    "generate": "yarn generate:types && yarn generate:types:lint"
  },
```

And then just run the script `yarn generate`.

Comment: we are using prettier to format files, but the concept is same. format the files after they are generated.